# No such file or directory: 'Tensorflow/workspace/annotations\\label_map.pbtxt on Jupyter why is my code not working?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter

I'm following this video [Real Time Face Mask Detection with Tensorflow and Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOI0o3Cxv9Q).

However, at the point in the video `21:06` when the developer creates the "Label map file" my file doesn't create on my local machine and I get an error on Jupyter which says `**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Tensorflow/workspace/annotations\\label_map.pbtxt'**`.

As you can see from the screenshot below, I have copied the code in the video I don't think I copied it over incorrectly on Jupyter.

**MY CODE**

```
labels = [{'name':'Mask', 'id':1}, {'name':'NoMask', 'id':2}]
     
with open(ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt', 'w') as f:
    for label in labels:
        f.write('item { \n')
        f.write('\tname:\'{}\'\n'.format(label['name']))
        f.write('\tid:{}\n'.format(label['id']))
        f.write('}\n')
```

**TUTORIAL CODE - 21:06 - CREATE MAP FILE**

[tutorial code on jupyter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB8QW.jpg)

As you can see from the next screenshot below, my path should be all correct I don't understand why the "label map" file is not creating?

[No label map file was created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM3B0.png)

I have also tried putting the slash in different ways for the file path like this `/` and this `\`.

Comment: Your python code looks like it is running out of a Temp directory. I'm not familiar with what `ANNOTATION_PATH`  is supposed to be, but from the error, it looks like that's not an absolute path, so it's looking in the temp directory.

Comment: Oh, also the error in your screenshot doesn't match the error you pasted. Can you please make the two consistent?

Comment: After writing my answer, I'm having doubts: can you check that the file really exists and that your script's current working directory is the parent dir of `Tensorflow`? Your error might just be that you're not in the right directory to find the file without an absolute path, as others have pointed out, or that the file outright does not exist, and maybe not at all about how you represent the filename...

Comment: To check, please run `print(os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir))` and check that it's the directory where `Tensorflow` exists. If not, then you'll know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use `os.path.join` to join path elements, or `pathlib.PurePath` to clean a mixed path variables

**Solution 1: use `os.path.join`**

When you are constructing file path names in Python, the safest thing to do is to use `os.path.join()` at every step. This will always give you portable code.

For example:

```py
import os

ANNOTATION_PATH = os.path.join("Tensorflow", "workspace", "annotations")
with open(os.path.join(ANNOTATION_PATH, "label_map.pbtxt", "w") as f:
    ...
```

If you run this code in a Windows-native Python interpreter, you will see that path components are systematically divided by `\` as they should be, and if you run the same code on Linux or in a Cygwin Python interpreter, you will see `/` between path components.

Ref: [`os.path.join` in the Python manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=os%20path%20join#os.path.join)

**Solution 2: use `pathlib.PurePath`**

The `pathlib` library in Python can be used to clean up mixed slash/backslash paths for you.

Tested on Windows:

```py
>>> import pathlib
>>> print(pathlib.PurePath('Tensorflow/workspace/annotations\\label_map.pbtxt'))
Tensorflow\workspace\annotations\label_map.pbtxt
```

Ref: [`pathlib` in the Python manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have redundant slash `\\`. Just remove one slash.

Use absolute path with drive letter, e.g. `r'C:\Users\NaziModerator\Tensorflow\workspace\annotations\label_map.pbtxt'`.

Do not mix `\` and `/`.

Don't forget about `r''` before string.

`print(path)` to be sure.

Comment: Thats what I thought. However, I tried that and it still didn't work :( - Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more solutions. Is it helpful now?

Comment: Still facing the same issue, updated the post as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Replace ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt' with r'c:\RealTimeObjectDetection\Tensorflow\workspace\annotations\label_map.pbtxt'